# Cannot get the value of float variable in the other class

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C but I do understand OO programming. Right now, I have this class where it gets the longitude and latitude of the current location. It prints out fine. The problem comes when I try to access it from another class. When I call getLatitude in the other class, it keeps giving me 0.000000 for both lat and long and I have really no clue how to fix it. I made the variable public and have getters and setters. It should be an easy fix, but I am very new to O-C.. Please help... I have ben stuck for days. Thank you.

**TableViewController.h**

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController{
    LocationSearchViewController *locationSearch;
}
@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

-(void)makeRestuarantRequests
{
    locationSearch = [[LocationSearchViewController alloc] init];

    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationSearch->longitude];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [locationSearch getLatitude]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=%@,%@&radius=100&query=restuarants&sensor=false&key=KEY", latitude, longitude]];

    NSLog(@"Long %@", longitude); ---> gives 0.000000
    NSLog(@"Lat %@", latitude);  ---> gives 0.000000
       .
       .
       .
    [operation start];
    }
```

LocationSearchViewController.h

```
@interface LocationSearchViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>{

@public float longitude;
@public float latitude;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
//@property (nonatomic, readwrite) float longitude;
//@property (nonatomic, readwrite) float latitude;

- (IBAction)currentLoc:(id)sender;
- (float) getLatitude;
- (float) getLongitude;
-(void) setLatitude:(float)latitude;
-(void) setLongitude:(float)longitude;

@end
```

LocationSearchViewController.m

```
@interface LocationSearchViewController ()
 @end

@implementation LocationSearchViewController {
      CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

@synthesize longitudeLabel = _longitudeLabel;
@synthesize latitudeLabel = _latitudeLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   }

- (IBAction)currentLoc:(id)sender { 
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
    .
    .
    .

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    NSLog(@"didUpdateLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

   [self setLongitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    [self setLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
  //longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    //latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    if(currentLocation != nil) {
        //returns current latitude and longitude
        self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f",  longitude];
        self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f",  latitude];
    } 
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}


- (float) getLatitude{
    return latitude;
    }

- (float ) getLongitude{
    return longitude;
}

-(void) setLatitude:(float)lati{
    latitude = lati;
}

-(void) setLongitude:(float)longti{
    longitude=longti;
}

@end
```

Comment: In `makeRestuarantRequests` function, you have created a new object of `LocationSearchViewController`. And since you are not modifying it in the function, I am not sure how any value other than 0 should be assigned to latitude/longitude.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about flow of your app but I think you are creating a new instance of LocationSearchViewController in your TableViewController that's why you are getting 0.000 value.

Can you please tell us the flow of your app so that it will be possible to understand your problem correctly ?

I would suggest to use delegate pattern so that you can pass the latitude & longitude received in LocationSearchViewController to TableViewController. Have a look at this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns) which describes design pattern in details

Comment: The root view (LocationSearch..) is where it gets the location. When I click the button, it searches for my location, and it does display. Then automatically(segue) it goes to the next screen which is the TableViewController. TableViewController uses API and gets the information of restaurants. I need to use the longitude and latitude to place in between of URL to get the restaurants near my location. Thank you for the link. I am looking into it right now.

Answer (score 0):

`LocationSearchViewController`'s locationManger will update location after `currentLoc:` is invoked. In `makeRestuarantRequests`, you instantiated `LocationSearchViewController` but `currentLoc:` looks not to invoked.

When `currentLoc` is invoked, you can get the coordinate value after the delegate method `-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation     *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation` invoked.